# Cómo mostrar una lista de una query en LINQ, de una tabla con atributos de otra Tabla que se relaciona de forma eficiente en asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, razor, webforms

Actualmente listo datos de la Tabla MIEMBROS más el nombre de la comuna(comuna_nombre) de la tabla COMUNA.Pero quiero hacerlo más eficiente, sin la necesidad de listar otros datos de la tabla COMUNA en vano.

Para especificar, muestro la siguiente relación (COMUNA y MIEMBROS):
[image: relacion por el id_comuna]

En mi Controller:

```
Function partialListadoMiembros(ByVal pag As Integer, ByVal cant_filas As Integer) As PartialViewResult
    Dim m As New ListadoMiembrosViewModels
    Using db As New BD_LOSCOPIHUESEntities1
        Dim ind_pag As Integer = (pag - 1) * cant_filas
        Dim miembros = db.MIEMBRO.Include("COMUNA").OrderBy(Function(x) x.ApellidoPaterno).Skip(ind_pag).Take(cant_filas)
        ' Dim miembros As List(Of MIEMBRO) = (From miemb In db.MIEMBRO Join com In db.COMUNA On com.id_comuna Equals miemb.id_comuna Select miemb, com)
        If miembros.Any Then
            m.listadoMiembros = miembros.ToList()
            m.listadoComunas = db.COMUNA.ToList
            ViewData("totalListadoMiembros") = db.MIEMBRO.Count()
        End If
    End Using
    Return PartialView(m)
End Function
```

En una clase que hice de ViewModel lo siguiente:

```
Public Class ListadoMiembrosViewModels
   Property listadoMiembros As List(Of MIEMBRO)
   Property listadoComunas As List(Of COMUNA)
End Class
```

En la vista:

```
 <% For Each item In Model.listadoMiembros%>
                            <tr id="fila_miembro_<%:item.Rut%>">
                                <td>
                                    <% If item.RutaFoto <> "" Then%>
                                    <img alt="" src='<%: item.RutaFoto%>'  height="120" width="180" class="img-responsive" />

                                    <%Else%>
                                         <label>Sin Imagen</label>    
                                    <%End If%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%: item.NombreFoto & " " & item.ApellidoPaterno & " " & item.ApellidoMaterno%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%: item.COMUNA.comuna_nombre%>
                                </td>
                        ....................................................
                        ....................................................
                        ............................................... 
                        ............................................
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿es posible listarse de manera más eficiente?, para no poder listar en vano toda la tabla COMUNA, ya que necesito solamente el nombre_comuna de la tabla COMUNA que tiene el MIEMBRO, ya que este ultimo, tiene el id_comuna para referenciarse. Posiblemente existe la posibilidad de hacer algún cruce de tabla, join, o alguna otra forma.
Desde ya, gracias por su atención, espero sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando realzias el include() de linq de las comunas ya agregas la referencia esa entidad, es mas veo que defines

```
<%: item.COMUNA.comuna_nombre%>
```

no veo para que defines en el modelo la propiedad

```
Property listadoComunas As List(Of COMUNA)
```

cuando no es necesaria

Sino la alternativa es aplanar los datos, para eso vas a necesitar convertir la clase de EF en una clase de Model, podrias definir algo como ser

```
Public Class MiembroModel

    //resto propiedades

    Public Property  As String

Ens Class


Public Class ListadoMiembrosViewModels
   Property listadoMiembros As List(Of MiembroModel)
End Class
```

y luego lo usarias

```
Function partialListadoMiembros(ByVal pag As Integer, ByVal cant_filas As Integer) As PartialViewResult

    Dim m As New ListadoMiembrosViewModels

    Using db As New BD_LOSCOPIHUESEntities1
        Dim ind_pag As Integer = (pag - 1) * cant_filas
        Dim miembros = db.MIEMBRO
                        .Include("COMUNA")
                        .Select(Function(x) New MiembroModel {
                            //otras propiedades
                            .ComunaDesc = x.COMUNA.comuna_nombre
                        })
                        .OrderBy(Function(x) x.ApellidoPaterno)
                        .Skip(ind_pag)
                        .Take(cant_filas)

        m.listadoMiembros = miembros.ToList()
        ViewData("totalListadoMiembros") = db.MIEMBRO.Count()
    End Using

    Return PartialView(m)

End Function
```

veras como en el Select() de linq asignas las porpiedades que vas a necesitar en la view, pero particularmente como se asigna la descripcion de la comuna en una propiedad simple

**>>el Property listadoComunas As List(Of COMUNA) era para listar una combobox que se me pasó en la pregunta. Estaba haciendo una query: Dim miembros = (From miemb In db.MIEMBRO Join com In db.COMUNA On com.id_comuna Equals miemb.id_comuna Select miemb, com).ToList pero me decia el siguiente error: value of type 'System.collection.generic.List(OF )' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.MIEMBRO)**

En este caso el linq esta devolviendo un tipo anonimo el cual no mapea con la clase, aqui tienes dos caminos, dejas que el resultado del linq sea anonimo o defiens un tipo que mepea con lo que retorna el Select()

o sea defines

```
Dim miembros = (From miemb In db.MIEMBRO _
                Join com In db.COMUNA On com.id_comuna Equals miemb.id_comuna _
                Select miemb, com).ToList()
```

veras que miembros no define ningun tipo, o sino defiens una clase como ser

```
Public Class MiembroModel
   Public Property miembro As MIEMBRO
   Public Property comuna As COMUNA
End Class
```

y la usas en el linq

```
Dim miembros As List(Of MiembroModel) = (From miemb In db.MIEMBRO _
                                    Join com In db.COMUNA On com.id_comuna Equals miemb.id_comuna _
                                    Select New MiembroModel { miembro= miemb, comuna = com }).ToList()
```

Comment: Hola Leandro Tuttini, el Property listadoComunas As List(Of COMUNA)  era para listar una combobox que se me pasó en la pregunta.
Estaba haciendo una query:

            Dim miembros = (From miemb In db.MIEMBRO Join com In db.COMUNA On com.id_comuna Equals miemb.id_comuna Select miemb, com).ToList

pero me decia el siguiente error:
value of type 'System.collection.generic.List(OF <anonymous type>)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.MIEMBRO)


....me gustaría tambien saber como podría hacerlo con el uso de JOIN en el linq

Comment: ahh ok, esto no lo mencuonaste en la pregunta, edito la respuesta para mencionar sobre este punto

Comment: Perfecto, era lo que necesitba